# how to read a text file input and load it to FTL template in xml format in java

Tags: java

My input has the data of 2 columns seperated by space like this
emp.name Tom
emp.age 18
dept.name sales
I want this details in a xml using ftl template
 
  Tom
  18


  sales

Can someone please help on this? i used a hashMap and made the input as key value pair and dono how to load in ftl template.

Comment: Will be off topic on stack overflow as you should provide the code and show where it goes wrong and whag should it do if correct.

Answer (score 0):

Use `freemarker.template.Configuration` and `java.io.StringWriter`; You will load key/values of hashmap into the template:

```
Configuration cfg = new Configuration();
Template template = cfg.getTemplate("path_of_template/template_name.ftl");     
StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter(); 
template.process(yourHashMap, stringWriter );
```

You may face problems if you don't use correct syntax in your FTL file or if you don't check *nulls*, etc.

Comment: @Ashima, You're welcome, For every question you ask , you can accept the answer that you feel answered your question correctly or was helpful or solved your problem.